Signature error when adding a delegate
I am trying to add a delegate to my safe in order to submit tx from a keeper.
I have read the API (v2) documentation and tried to sign an eip712 message. A problem is that the doc mentions that the delegate address field is of type bytes32, which does not match the length of an address. I tried to workaroun by changing the type to address, which allows me to sign the message but when submiting to the API, I get a error as the signature is not matching the delegator address (my ledger address).
Did I do anything wrong ?
I also tried to sign the (much simple) v1 message format using this script for reference (https://github.com/AngleProtocol/angle-multisig/blob/main/addDelegate.py) but I also get the same error message
I am signing correctly the message using my ledger to the problem seems to be on the API end.

If the parameter is bytes32, you can convert the address to bytes 32 like this - bytes32(uint256(uint160(addr)))

@ZartajAfser I can sign the message but I still get the same error about the signature not matching the delegator
